# How to split elements from a list, into different columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values `[0.1, 0.43, 0.58]` and a dataframe `df` with several columns. I added three new columns in my dataframe with `NaN` values, and I want to replace them with the ones from the list. Each list value split into each new column in that exact order.

The dataframe is 4 columns (no index shown), with 3 new columns.

```
Name  A    B    C     New1  New2  New3
Elem1 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Elem2 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Elem3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Expected result:

```
Name  A    B    C     New1  New2  New3
Elem1 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Elem2 NaN  NaN  NaN   0.1   0.43  0.58
Elem3 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'Elem2', df.columns[4:]] = [0.1, 0.43, 0.58]`

Comment: @It_is_Chris please add your code as an answer, because comments get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If `l` is your list, then:

```
df.loc[df.Name=='Elem2', 'New1':'New3'] = l
```